# In Firebase Firestore, I want to use orderBy twice. Do I need to create an index to speed up the query?

Tags: javascript, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Firestore, I want to use orderBy twice. Do I need to create an index to speed up the query?

For example:

```
Query query = fsDB.collection("users").document(currentUID).collection("received_messages")
.orderBy("messageSeen").orderBy("date");
```

There is no automatic Error message that shows up like when using ranges or "where".

Structure looks like:

```
received_messages

  date:  01/02/99

  messageSeen:  true

  from:  keuajopdf315
```

Should I put an index on the collection "received messages" and the "messageSeen" and "date" fields to speed up the query?

Comment: When I try to run a query with two `orderBy()` clauses, I get an error: "The query requires an index. You can create it here:". Are you sure the index doesn't exist already?

Comment: After adding the index that is linked in the error message, I can then retrieve the documents ordered-by-state-then-by-index. See https://jsbin.com/rewujav/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to run a query with two orderBy() clauses, I get an error:

> The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...

After adding the index that is linked in the error message, I can then retrieve the documents ordered-by-state-then-by-index. See my working jsbin here: https://jsbin.com/rewujav/edit?js,console

```
docs.orderBy("state").orderBy("index").get().then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id+": state="+doc.data().state+" index="+doc.data().index);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you Frank, I couldn't find the error in the console until you mentioned this.

Comment: FYI anyone reading this, In Android Studio, this does not show up as an "Error" in the logical.  I had to actually go in, set it to "Verbose" and type "The query requires an index."  In order for it to pop up in the logcat.

Comment: That sounds unintentional Jeff, we actually want these messages to be easily findable. Can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)? We'll also try to reproduce.

Comment: Ok, just filed bug report.  I was using Android Studio 2.3.  "The query require an index" appears in blue text, which signifies "debug" in Android, rather than the red Error in the Logcat.  The App was also able to run on my device (the compiler did not stop me from running the app, and it still worked on the device).